# Google Drive API and Mobile

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am building a website where the user logs in and connects to his/her google drive ! That works fine and even if I test it through my mobile... BUT!

Is it possible whenever the user clicks on a document, instead of opening the document on a new tab, it opens in the google drive app ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `alternateLink` field of the Drive file metadata to open the file using a relevant Google editor or viewer:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#alternateLink

Comment: yeah that is what i am using ! and when i click it, it opens in a webpage instead of the drive app itself.. I just would like to know if it's possible or not ?